# AchartEngine graph point background color to white

Tags: android, achartengine

Hello, I want to change the background color of **graphPoint** to white . So I created another series and set its color to white. But, now I just want to display graphPoint only not graph line because white line are also display over blue color line. I also tried to set line width to 0 but nothing happened.

What should I do?

Here is my current series code show below:

```
XYSeriesRenderer getFakeSeriesRenderer(){
        XYSeriesRenderer r_fake=new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r_fake.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        r_fake.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        r_fake.setPointStrokeWidth(getPixels(1));
        r.setLineWidth(0.0f);
        r_fake.setFillPoints(true);
        r_fake.setDisplayChartValuesDistance((int)getPixels((int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chart_value_distance)));
        r_fake.setChartValuesTextSize((int)getPixels((int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chart_text_size)));
        return r_fake;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is your graph zoomable and scrollable?

Comment: Yup @keshav but why are you asking?

Comment: Have u solved ur problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a scatter chart instead of the line chart you are currently building.